# how to get secret_key_base in aws?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, secret-key

I am continuing with the development in ruby on rails of a project from another programmer, the project was hosted in aws, the project references a key called secret_key_base. The problem is that that key is not in the project and I am working on another aws account so that key was lost. Is there any way to generate it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is referenced as ENV variable then it must in the aws config. The other option is it may in `config/credentials.yml.enc` file or similar to this. For more information you can check this [guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials). If it is lost completely then you can create a new random string with running `rake secret`. But please be aware that if previous key for example used to encrypt some data in database then you won't be able to decrypt them.